# Multiple playlists on VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Winamp, QMMP, and even Rhythmbox can have multiple playlists pinned on there interface. The user can select any of those playlists and play their songs instantly, without the need to find where those playlists are located on the disk.

Do you know if VLC has the same thing? If yes, how I can do it? If not, is there any workaround that I can do? I've searched a lot, but I found no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add playlists to VLC Media Player's Media Library.
Drag and drop playlists into the Media Library like this:

[image: VLC playlists]

Comment: Great graphical explanation

Comment: I know this topic is old, but there is a small problem with this answer. If you then choose to play the playlist within the media library, the media library acts as one big playlist in terms of shuffle and next. So if you turn shuffle on, you will skip around all your playlists. It is still annoying that VLC only has one "current" playlist and if you truly want to jump from one playlist to another, you need to clear out the current "Playlist", and add your new playlist (from "Media Library") to the "Playlist". It's a couple extra steps that solutions like iTunes don't require.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> preferences -> interface -> 'use only one instance when started from file manager'....
Uncheck it, save.
Now you can use multiple instances of VLC at the same time, drag-drop files for multiple playlists.
:)